# Where is the file which stores the default run configurations of Java projects in Eclipse on a Mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, setup-project

It seems eclipse on a Mac store its run configurations in a different location from its linux/win version.

I'm using Eclipse for Java on Mac OSX 10.6.8. It is installed without changing anything default.

Here are version numbers.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers   1.2.2.20100216-1730 epp.package.java
  Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools   6.0.2.201002161416  org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group

Any comments are very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not actually change from platform to platform. You should be able to find the run configs here:

```
<your workspace folder>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

Comment: Thanks! I find all the run configs there. I copied all my projects from the default workspace folder to a new folder (months ago), that's why I didn't find it there.